# Code to search for combinations of characters in a two-dimensional array doesn't output anything

Tags: arrays, c, multidimensional-array

This code if supposed to first take a line of inputs of combinations of characters each separated by space, then no more than 10 rows of inputs, all of equal length but no longer than 10 characters, then search for the combinations of characters from the first line in the two-dimensional array. This is the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define WORDNUM 100
#define SIZE 10


int getWords(char wordMatrix[WORDNUM][100]){

    char c;
    int i=0, j=0;

    while ((c=fgetc(stdin)) != '\n'){
        if (isalpha(c)){
            wordMatrix[i][j]=c;
            j++;
        }
        else if(c==' '){
            i++;
            j=0;
        }
    }

    return i+1;
}


int getMatrix( char matrix[SIZE][SIZE]){

    char c;
    int i=0, j;

    while ((c=fgetc(stdin)) != EOF && i < (SIZE)){
        if (isalpha(c)){
            matrix[i][j]=c;
            j++;
        }
        else if(c=='\n'){
            i++;
            j=0;
        }
    }

    return i;
}


int checkExist(int rowM , int xM, int rowNum, int rowLen, char *word, char matrix[SIZE][SIZE]){
    int xW=1;
    int direction;

    direction = -1;
    while((rowM + direction) > 0){
        if(matrix[xM][rowM+direction] == word[xW]){
            xW++;

            if(xW == strlen(word)) return 1;

            else direction--;
            
        }

        else break;
    }

    direction = -1;
    while((xM + direction) > 0){
        if(matrix[xM+direction][rowM] == word[xW]){
            xW++;

            if(xW == strlen(word)) return 1;

            else direction--;
        }

        else break;
    }

    direction = 1;
    while((rowM + direction) < rowNum){
        if(matrix[xM][rowM+direction] == word[xW]){
            xW++;

            if(xW == strlen(word)) return 1;

            else direction++;
        }

        else break;
    }

    direction = 1;
    while((xM + direction) < rowLen ){
        if(matrix[xM+direction][rowM] == word[xW]){
            xW++;
            
            if(xW == strlen(word)) return 1;

            else direction++;
        }

        else break;
    }

    return 0;
}


int checkMatrix(int rowNum, int rowLen, char *word, char matrix[SIZE][SIZE]){

    int xM, rowM, check;

    for(rowM=0; rowM < rowNum; rowM++){
        for(xM=0; xM < rowLen; xM++){
            if(word[0] == matrix[rowM][xM]){
                if(strlen(word) == 1) return 1;
                else if (strlen(word)>1 && (check = checkExist(rowM, xM, rowNum, rowLen, word, matrix)) == 1) return 1;
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}


int main() {

    char word[WORDNUM][100], matrix[SIZE][SIZE];
    int logRowNumW, logRowNumM, logRowLen, rowW, x, check;

    logRowNumW = getWords(word);

    logRowNumM = getMatrix(matrix);

    logRowLen = strlen(matrix[0]);    

    for(rowW=0; rowW <logRowNumW; rowW++){
        if((check = checkMatrix(logRowNumM, logRowLen, word[rowW], matrix)) == 1){
            for(x=0; x<strlen(word[rowW]); x++){
                printf("%c", word[rowW][x]);
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Problem is, it doesn't output anything, correct or incorrect, just nothing. Thanks for any and all advice

Edit: As it turns out, two stupid mistakes were at fault. First, xW ins't reset for each direction in checkExist and second, I mixed up xM and rowM in checkExist, it works well now.

Comment: Edit the question to provide sample input that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Aside: note that `char c;` for use with `fgetc()` should be `int c;` . Also I'm baffled how you could write so much code, that doesn't output anything. Advance the work in small steps, checking it performs as intended as you go.

Comment: `strlen(word))` is UB as your `word` is not null character temniated.

Comment: The function ```checkMatrix()``` always returns 0, and you only print anything inside of the if statement ```if checkMatrix() == 1```

Comment: If input to `getWords()` contain a leading space you also will have trouble.  You don't do any boundary checks (i.e. less than 100).

Comment: In getMatrix() you don't initialize `j`.

Comment: To @0___________'s point neither word or matrix are '\0' terminated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `getWords()`, `getMatrix()`: `fgetc()` returns an `int` (not a `char`) and it's particular important when you are checking against `EOF` in `getMatrix()`.
2. `getWords()`, `getMatrix()`: You don't terminate `wordMatrix` or `matrix` with '\0' so anything that relies on those being strings (ie `strlen()`) will trigger undefined behavior.
3. `getWords()` probably should skip leading spaces.
4. `getMatrix()` you need to initialize `j`.
5. (Not fixed) Introduce a MAX_WORD_LEN or similar for the 2nd 100 magic value, and use that upper bound when you iterate through your matrix to avoid buffer overflow.  Or consider using `getline()` to dynamically allocate space for your input.
6. (Not fixed) Consider using `strtok()` for parsing your string into words.  Note, it changes the input string, it's a little more work but `strpbrk()` or `strch()` can be used to locate your delimiter but you do need to handle initial, consecutive and trailing delimiters yourself.

With those initial 4 changes:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define WORDNUM 100
#define SIZE 10

int getWords(char wordMatrix[WORDNUM][100]){
    int c;
    int i=0, j=0;
    while ((c=fgetc(stdin)) != '\n') {
        if (isalpha(c)){
            wordMatrix[i][j]=c;
            j++;
        } if(c==' ') {
            if(!j) continue;
            wordMatrix[i][j] = '\0';
            i++;
            j=0;
        }
    }
    wordMatrix[i][j] = '\0';
    return i+1;
}


int getMatrix( char matrix[SIZE][SIZE]){
    int c;
    int i=0, j = 0;
    while ((c=fgetc(stdin)) != EOF && i < (SIZE)){
        if (isalpha(c)){
            matrix[i][j]=c;
            j++;
        }
        else if(c=='\n'){
            matrix[i][j] = '\0';
            i++;
            j=0;
        }
    }
    // If last line can be terminated with EOF instead of \n
    // then you need another '\0':
    // matrix[i][j] = '\0';
    return i;
}


int checkExist(int rowM , int xM, int rowNum, int rowLen, char *word, char matrix[SIZE][SIZE]){
    int xW=1;
    int direction;

    direction = -1;
    while((rowM + direction) > 0){
        if(matrix[xM][rowM+direction] == word[xW]){
            xW++;

            if(xW == strlen(word)) return 1;

            else direction--;

        }

        else break;
    }

    direction = -1;
    while((xM + direction) > 0){
        if(matrix[xM+direction][rowM] == word[xW]){
            xW++;

            if(xW == strlen(word)) return 1;

            else direction--;
        }

        else break;
    }

    direction = 1;
    while((rowM + direction) < rowNum){
        if(matrix[xM][rowM+direction] == word[xW]){
            xW++;

            if(xW == strlen(word)) return 1;

            else direction++;
        }

        else break;
    }

    direction = 1;
    while((xM + direction) < rowLen ){
        if(matrix[xM+direction][rowM] == word[xW]){
            xW++;
            if(xW == strlen(word)) return 1;
            else direction++;
        }
        else break;
    }
    return 0;
}


int checkMatrix(int rowNum, int rowLen, char *word, char matrix[SIZE][SIZE]){
    for(int rowM=0; rowM < rowNum; rowM++){
        for(int xM=0; xM < rowLen; xM++){
            if(word[0] == matrix[rowM][xM]){
                if(strlen(word) == 1) return 1;
                else if (strlen(word)>1 && (checkExist(rowM, xM, rowNum, rowLen, word, matrix) == 1)) return 1;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}


int main() {
    char word[WORDNUM][100], matrix[SIZE][SIZE];
    int logRowNumW = getWords(word);
    int logRowNumM = getMatrix(matrix);
    int logRowLen = strlen(matrix[0]);
    for(int rowW=0; rowW <logRowNumW; rowW++){
        if((checkMatrix(logRowNumM, logRowLen, word[rowW], matrix)) == 1){
            for(int x=0; x<strlen(word[rowW]); x++){
                printf("%c", word[rowW][x]);
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Your program now generates output:

```
a
ab
cd
<EOF>
a
```

Using the supplied input (I think) in comment here is how I would write a hard-coded test case and revise the code along the lines discussed in the comments to my answer:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define N 10
#define NORTH {-1, 0}
#define EAST {0, 1}
#define SOUTH {1, 0}
#define WEST {0, -1}

int checkExist(int r, int c, int m, int n, const char *word, const char matrix[][N]) {
    if(word[0] != matrix[r][c])
        return 0;
    const int directions[][2] = { NORTH, EAST, SOUTH, WEST };
    for(int d = 0; d < sizeof directions / sizeof *directions; d++) {
        int w = 1;
        for(int r2 = r + directions[d][0], c2 = c + directions[d][1]; r2 >= 0 && r2 < m && c2 >= 0 && c2 < n && word[w]; r2 += directions[d][0], c2 += directions[d][1], w++)
            if(word[w] != matrix[r2][c2])
                break;
        if(!word[w])
            return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

int checkMatrix(int m, int n, const char *word, const char matrix[][N]){
    for(int r=0; r < m; r++)
        for(int c=0; c < n; c++)
            if(checkExist(r, c, m, n, word, matrix))
                return 1;
    return 0;
}

int main(void) {
    char *word[] = {
        "oh",
        "to",
        "lot",
        "kol",
        "lok",
        "tol",
        "mol",
        "ho",
        "jol",
        "loj",
        "lol"
    };
    int words = sizeof word / sizeof *word;
    char matrix[][N] = {
        "john",
        "moto",
        "tolo"
    };
    int m = sizeof matrix / sizeof *matrix;
    int n = strlen(matrix[0]);
    for(int w=0; w < words; w++)
        if((checkMatrix(m, n, word[w], matrix)))
            printf("%s\n", word[w]);
}
```

and this non-interactive program returns:

```
oh
to
lot
tol
ho
```

which I believe is the correct output.

If `word[w]` matches then `reverse(word[w])` would, too.  You could pre-process `word` into an array of `struct { char *word, int has_reverse }`, so in the above `{ "oh", 1 }, { "to", 0 }, ...`.  If the word matches you also print out the reverse if `has_reverse` is true.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Sadly the changes you provided didn't help much. Now it sometimes works but there's no rhyme or reason to it when it doesn't. For 
oh to lot kol lok tol mol ho jol loj lol
john
moto
tolo 
 it spat out
to lot tol ho
,for   
k kk kol lok lo ola ok ko okk
kola 
its only output was k. I suppose I'll have to figure out points 5 and 6 of your answer and rewrite my code once again

Comment: I suggest you accept the answer and file a new question if you need help with the intermittent issue.  The key is to include test data, a particular power way of  doing that is to hard-code a failing test case (in the data you provided what is words and what is the matrix?).  This eliminates the two input helper functions as either irrelevant or the root cause.

Comment: 5 & 6 are probably unrelated to issue at hand.

Comment: In `checkMatrix()` you check if the first letter match, special case if there is 1 letter in word.   I suggest you push that special case, if you want it, into `checkExists()`.

Comment: `checkExist()` you have essential the same code duplicates 4 times.  Create an array with each of the directions you want to check `{ {0, -1}, {0,1}, {-1,0}, {1, 0} }' then iterate over the array.  The only tweak you want check both upper and lower bounds on both row and column with similar code that you have now.